# How to restart from word point with for loop - BashScript

Tags: bash

I try made a restore point from 9F4A but i have no idea how did it

```
punto_de_restauracion="9F4A"
a=9
b=F
c=4
d=A
for a in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
do
    for b in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
    do
            for c in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
            do
                    for d in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
                    do
                            echo "$a$b$c$d"
                    done
            done
    done
done
```

I try restart a for loop, start from -> 9F4A and increment

Comment: What do you mean? It is unclear what you're asking, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I try restart loop from 9F4A

Comment: At which point in the code? What is the desired output of the script? Please [edit] to add more details.

Comment: @BashScript, should the first line of output be `9F4A` (rerunning the state saved as the restore point), or should it be `9F45` (beginning at the next state *after* the restore point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're asking is how to exit from all the nested do loops when a=9, b=F, c=4 and d=A.  If so, you want the shell command "break":

```
#!/bin/sh
#punto_de_restauracion="9F4A"
for a in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
do
    for b in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
    do
        for c in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
        do
            for d in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7
            do
                echo "$a$b$c$d"
                if [ "$a" == "9" -a "$b" == "F" -a "$c" == "4" -a "$d" == "A" ] ; then
                    break 4
                fi
            done
        done
    done
done
```

You can get more information on the "break" command in the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section of the "sh" man page.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to *start* at that point, not *stop* at it.

Comment: Also, note that `==` is not guaranteed to work in `[` in `/bin/sh`; the only POSIX-guaranteed string comparison operator is `=`. On a similar point, `-a` is marked obsolescent; `[ "$a" = 9 ] && [ "$b" = F ] ...` is better form. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, noting the `[OB XSI]` notation where pertinent.

Answer (score -1):

The easy thing to do is set a flag when the point from which you want to restart is reached, and avoid actually taking actions inside your loop until that flag is set. Using `continue` skips the inner loops, so you don't bother iterating through values of `b`, `c` or `d` when you haven't yet found the right `a` (for example).

```
restart_point="9F4A"

if [[ $restart_point ]]; then
  started=0
else
  started=1
fi

not_started() {
  (( started == 1 )) && return 1   # if started is true, we're not not_started (false!)
  [[ ${1:$2:1} != "$3" ]] && return 0 # otherwise, with no match, we're not_started (true!)
  [[ $final ]] && started=1        # w/ match, if "final" is set, set "started" flag
  return 1                         # since we found a match earlier, we're true.
}

for a in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7; do
  not_started "$restart_point" 0 "$a" && continue
  for b in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7; do
    not_started "$restart_point" 1 "$b" && continue
    for c in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7; do
      not_started "$restart_point" 2 "$c" && continue
      for d in 4 A 5 9 E 3 F 6 C 2 7; do
        final=1 not_started "$restart_point" 3 "$d" && continue
        echo "$a$b$c$d"
      done
    done
  done
done
```